# SQL Server 2012 - Case statement in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, case, where-clause

SQL is not my strong suit, but I cannot figure out why this isn't working. I simply want to run a different AND statement based on a value. Specifically, I want to change the datePart in the dateDiff function if foo is = 0

```
SELECT foo,
       bar,
       test
FROM table
WHERE bar = 1,
CASE WHEN foo = 0
        AND dateDiff(dd, getDate(), 2 ) < test
ELSE
        AND dateDiff(hh, getDate(), 2 ) < test
END
```

Comment: You got syntax errors in your query

Comment: I don't know why but this is a common mistake people make in SQL - they introduce a `CASE` expression when really, all they really need is the basic logical operators.

Comment: Damien, care to extrapolate?

Comment: As in Devart's answer, all you need to say is `(foo = 0 AND DATEDIFF(dd,...) OR foo!=0 AND DATEDIFF(hh,...))`

Comment: Although now I come to look at it, I'm fairly certain, whatever you were aiming for, those `DATEDIFF` calls aren't doing what you think they are. Hint: `DATEDIFF` returns an integer, which (if being compared with a `datetime`) will be implicitly converted to a `datetime` as a number of days since `1900-01-01`. And the third parameter to `DATEDIFF` is meant to be a date, `2` will be implicitly converted to `1900-01-03`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this one -

```
SELECT foo,
       bar,
       test
FROM [table]
WHERE bar = 1
    AND (
            (
                foo = 0 
                AND 
                DATEDIFF(dd, GETDATE(), 2 ) < test
            )
        OR  
            DATEDIFF(hh, GETDATE(), 2 ) < test
        )
```

Comment: Not following this.. Where is the case to say only use DD if foo = 0

Comment: This is the equal expression. Why you need `CASE`?

Answer (score 5):

You can try like this

```
SELECT foo,
       bar,
       test
FROM table
WHERE bar = 1 And
(CASE WHEN foo = 0
    then   dateDiff(dd, getDate(), 2 )
ELSE
       dateDiff(hh, getDate(), 2 ) 
END)<test
```

Comment: `Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'.`

Answer (score 5):

If I had to guess at what you're actually aiming for, it's that you wanted to subtract 2 hours or days from `GETDATE()` for use in your comparison.

Here's what I think you're aiming for:

```
SELECT foo,
       bar,
       test
FROM table
WHERE bar = 1 AND
(
   (foo = 0 AND DATEADD(day,-2, GETDATE()) < test)
   OR
   (foo<>0 AND DATEADD(hour,-2,GETDATE()) < test)
)
```

I can't think that you really intended those `DATEDIFF` calls. For example, today (3rd July 2013), this expression:

```
select CAST(DATEDIFF(dd,getdate(),2) as datetime)
```

Produces `1786-07-03`<sup>1</sup>. I'm assuming that `test` is a `datetime` and that the implicit conversion is being performed. Even if it's not, the numerical value of `DATEDIFF(dd,getdate(),2)` will always be a large negative number (unless or until it's run on a machine where `GETDATE()` returns a value from before the 20th Century)

---

<sup>1</sup> Weirdly, I think 3rd July is the only day of the year on which the result will have the same month and day number.

Comment: Sorry Damien, my initial example was wrong. I am comparing 2 dates and not an int as the 3rd param. Thanks for the thorough follow up though!