# Query: add condition to where if a column is empty

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, query-optimization

I'm working on this query in a stored procedure. The data structure in simplified terms looks like this: a table containing the tables:

- Person
- Elec_Nominations
- Elec_Vacancy
- Ward
- Sector

What happens is a number of vacant seats are set for a sector within a ward. Individuals that are nominated for a seat are inputted into the `Person` database and linked to `Elec_Nominations`. This nomination is linked to `Ward` through `Elec_Vacancy`. The Nomination is also linked to the Sector (`ELEC_SPEAKER_SECTOR`) through `Elec_Vacancy` and some further link tables:

[image: Sector Seats]

The query I'm working on

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    p.PERSON_ID,
    p.ID_NUMBER,
    CONCAT(p.FULLNAMES, (CONCAT((' ' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS), p.SURNAME))) AS NAME,
    o.ORG_NAME,
    eiw.INTEREST_WARD_ID,
    scw.SUBCOUNCIL_ID,
    w.WARD_ID,
    ess.SPEAKER_SECTOR_ID,
    (SELECT TOP 1
     essg.NO_OF_SEATS
     FROM
         ELEC_SPEAKER_SECTOR_GROUP essg
         INNER JOIN ELEC_VACANCY ev ON essg.VACANCY_ID = ev.VACANCY_ID
     WHERE
         ev.VACANCY_ID = en.VACANCY_ID
     ORDER BY
         essg.ELEC_SECTOR_GROUP_SECTORS_ID DESC) AS SECTORSEATS,
    en.SECTOR_TEXT AS SECTORTEXT
    --essg.NO_OF_SEATS AS [SECTORSEATS]
FROM
    PERSON p
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
    ELEC_NOMINATIONS en ON p.PERSON_ID = en.PERSON_ID
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
    ELEC_INTEREST_WARD eiw ON en.INTEREST_WARD_ID = eiw.INTEREST_WARD_ID
LEFT JOIN 
    ELEC_INTEREST_GROUP eig ON eiw.INTEREST_GROUP_ID = eig.INTEREST_GROUP_ID
LEFT JOIN 
    ORGANISATION o ON eig.ORG_ID = o.ORG_ID
LEFT JOIN 
    WARD w ON eiw.WARD_ID = w.WARD_ID
LEFT JOIN 
    ELEC_SPEAKER_SECTOR ess ON eiw.SPEAKER_SECTOR_ID = ess.SPEAKER_SECTOR_ID
LEFT JOIN 
    SUBCOUNCILWARD scw ON w.WARD_ID = scw.WARD_ID
    --INNER JOIN ELEC_VACANCY ev ON en.VACANCY_ID = ev.VACANCY_ID
    --INNER JOIN ELEC_SPEAKER_SECTOR_GROUP essg ON ev.VACANCY_ID = essg.VACANCY_ID
WHERE
    ess.SPEAKER_SECTOR_ID IN (SELECT s.item FROM ufn_SplitIntArray(@P_Sectors, ',') s)
    AND w.WARD_ID IN (SELECT s.item FROM ufn_SplitIntArray(@P_Wards, ',') s)
    AND o.ORG_ID = @P_Org_ID
    --AND en.ELECTED = 1
ORDER BY
    w.WARD_ID
```

The output of this query go's into this `GridView`:

[image: Sector Seats Gv]

OK, I still need to get some clarity from the client as to how the sector seats are determined. The problem is that if I say `en.Elected = 1`, it shows only the persons who were elected as it should, but it doesn't show the sectors and wards where there isn't even a vacancy (ie. the 3rd and 5th row won't show).

As I'm typing this, I thought of something. I will try and research to determine if I can do something like this:

```
AND EVAL(ISNULL(en.NOMINATION_ID, 1))
```

Or something in SQL like:

```
if(en.NOMINATION_ID == null)
    true
else
    en.Elected == true
```

Comment: AND (en.NOMINATION_ID is Null or en.Elected = 1) something like?

Comment: @deadulya: Actualy, yes. In the end it's so simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use case clause:

```
and columnfilter = case when columnempty is null then (condition) else columnfilter
```

Also, refer to these answeres:

[SQL Server 2012 - Case statement in where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441179/sql-server-2012-case-statement-in-where-clause)

["CASE" statement within "WHERE" clause in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785209/case-statement-within-where-clause-in-sql-server-2008)